# Two questions about divisible

Tags: number-theory

I have two questions.

1) Why the relation $a^n\equiv a^{n+4k}\pmod{10}$ is true?

2) Let $(a,90)=1$. Which number can be $ x$ in $ x\mid a^4-1$? Answer is $240$. Why?

Comment: A hint on 1) is $\varphi(10)=4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
3^0 & \equiv 1 \pmod{10} \\
3^1 & \equiv 3 \pmod{10} \\
3^2 & \equiv 9 \pmod{10} \\
3^3 & = 27 \equiv 7 \pmod{10} \\
3^4 & = 81 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}
\end{align}
We've returned to $1$ when the exponent is $4$.

Try this with other numbers is $\{1,3,7,9\}$ in place of $3$.  In each case we get the $4$th power congruent to $1$.  The four numbers $1,3,7,9$ are those that are coprime to $10$.